# NodeJS defining param name of glob value in url

Tags: node.js, express, routes

Hi there I'm defining my get as below:

```
app.get('/list/:productType/*',  middleware.isAuthenticated, function (req, res) {

});
```

Using this I am able to get the value of productType by calling the  `req.params.productType`. The question is, however. How to do get the rest of the URL defined by the * global rule in the same way that I'd grab the productType parameter.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a direct way to achieve this, you have two options

1) you can be more specific in defining the route e.g. '/list/:productType/:version/' and access the parameter using req.params.version

2) you can use `req.url` property to get the full request url and manually parse path after `/:productType`.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out the answer: When console logging req.params the object has the "wildcard" string in the root index of this object. Thanks guys!